# osascript keystroke character case with VMware web console

Tags: applescript, safari, script, vmware

Looking to get the ability to simulating typing a password into a vm console. Figured osascript and keystroke should be the answer.

If I run the following I get what I believe to be the correct behaviour in the terminal.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
set UC to "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÅÄÖ"
set lc to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö"

#tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
  repeat with c in (the clipboard)
    considering case
      if UC contains c then
         key down shift
         keystroke "u" #c
         key up shift
      else
        keystroke "l" #c
      end if
    end considering
  end repeat
end tell
```

Result with `stackEXCHANGE` in clipboard:

```
➜  ~ ./send_keys.osa    
lllllUUUUUUUU%                                                                        ➜  ➜  ~  lllllUUUUUUUU
```

Adding the tell to activate Safari I expect something similar to end up in my VMware vm console terminal - however:

[image: lc only]

The context is successfully switched to the Safari vm console window and the string is written correctly except all characters are lower case. The `key down shift` and `key up switch` which work fine in terminal (or in other web sites I tested), does **not** work in the vm console.

How can I get keystroke to send characters in the correct case to the vm console? (Or - is there another way to get the string into the vm console?)

Comment: If it is specific to VMware Console, I assume that a simple `tell application "System Events" to  keystroke "v" using command down` also doesn't work? Looks like VMware uses some Javascript here to prevent stuff.

Comment: Precisely - it is because I cannot paste into the window I turned to osascript.

Comment: I add successes in a similar case where I could not input keystrokes to use a python script simulating GUI scripting. You might try that by activating the keyboard in the menu bar. Obviously a fragile solution.